# If-clause on content of variable

Tags: equality

**Question:**

I customized the variable `user-mail-address` on PC 1 and thought, I simply could ask for the content of this variable:

```
(setq org-agenda-files
  (if  (user-mail-address "Keks@Dose.org")
   '(("100-23" . "/mnt/Server1/2023/100-23/%s")
...
```

But that does not work, because `user-mail-address` is a variable, the email adress is a string and I have no idea, how to write that if-clause correctly. I read about `cond`, but in the end I'll probably spent the whole afternoon on this matter.

So any help appreciated to fix this if clause. If you prefer a `cond` expression, very well.

Comment: Please fix the title: it seems to be completely disconnected from the body of the question. Also `elisp` is almost never a good tag: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @NickD Yes, you are right, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a function that compares strings to see if they are equal:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-files
      (if (equal user-mail-address "Keks@Dose.org")
          '(("100-23" . "/mnt/Server1/2023/100-23/%s")
            …
```